# Smooth maps into an immersed submanifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Quote *An introduction to manifolds*:

[image]
[image]

In the pictures $f(t) = (\cos t,\sin 2t)$ and $g(t) = (\cos t,−\sin 2t)$

I'm completely confused here, he is proving that $\overline{f}$ is not continuous if $S$ has the induced topology from $g$. But this seems like cheating really, and $S$ is not even a manifold in the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Is there an honest example, where $S$ is a manifold in the subspace topology and $f:N\to S$ is not smooth? I know that if in addition $S$ is a regular submanifold then it is always true.

Comment: You should also reproduce here his definition of topology on S: this is not the subspace topology.

Comment: The bottom line is: Avoid the notion of an "immersed submanifold", use only regular submanifolds and immersions (which are maps, not subsets).

Comment: @studiosus "$S$ has the induced topology from $g$".